# Determine whether a type exists without feature-test macro

Tags: c++, templates, types

I'd like to determine whether a type exists *without* using a feature-test macro.  Here's the idea **using** a macro:

```
namespace real
{
    struct foo final { static constexpr const char* name = "real::foo"; };
}
#define real_foo_ 314

struct my_foo final { static constexpr const char* name = "my_foo"; };
namespace real
{
#if !real_foo_
    using foo = my_foo;
#endif
}
```

That is, `real::foo` should to the "`real`" `foo` if it exists, otherwise `my_foo` will be used; subsequent code uses `real::foo` w/o knowing or caring whether it's the actual version or the replacement.

Achiving the same [template meta-programming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190710-00/?p=102678) seems to be the right idea:

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace real
{
    struct bar final { static constexpr const char* name = "real::bar"; };
}

struct my_bar final { static constexpr const char* name = "my_bar"; };

// https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190710-00/?p=102678
template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_type_complete_v = false;
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_type_complete_v<T, std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T))>> = true;

namespace real { struct bar; }
namespace real
{
    using bar = std::conditional_t<is_type_complete_v<real::bar>, real::bar, my_bar>;
}
```

The above works as shown:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    real::foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.name << "\n";

    real::bar bar;
    std::cout << bar.name << "\n";
}
```

But removing the actual definition (not the forward) of `real::bar` causes compiler errors:

```
namespace real
{
    //struct bar final { static constexpr const char* name = "real::bar"; };
}
```

> error C2371: 'real::bar': redefinition; different basic types
> message : see declaration of 'real::bar'
> error C2079: 'bar' uses undefined struct 'real::bar'

Is there a way to make `real::bar` work like `real::foo` **without** relying on a feature-test macro?  Note that as with `real::foo`, the name of `real::bar` can't be changed (e.g., to `real::really_bar`).

---

(Actual use case: C++14/C++17/C++20 library features implemented in C++11; once client code using `std::filesystem::path` has been written, it shouldn't have to change.)

Comment: What is wrong to check for `currentVersion => C++17` in code?

Comment: There are bad usages of MACRO. But some are correct (I consider branching from preprocessor a correct one). Alternative to preprocessor directive might use tool chain to choose which file to include/exclude from the build, generate some file from some template (`"real.h.in"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler complains on your code because you are trying to create two entities with same name. Consider changing

```
namespace real
{
    struct bar final { static constexpr const char* name = "real::bar"; };
}
```

to something like

```
namespace real
{
    struct absolutely_bar final { static constexpr const char* name = "real::bar"; };
}
...
namespace real { struct absolutely_bar; }
namespace real
{
    using bar = std::conditional_t<is_type_complete_v<real::absolutely_bar>, real::absolutely_bar, my_bar>;
}
```

PS: creating such aliases is usually a bad pattern since it's not obvious.